# Beamer: getting rid of outline frames in the overall count

Tags: beamer, numbering, frame

I have a problem with Beamer: I would like the overall frame count to take into account only the frames with actual content.

Here there is an MWE:

```
\documentclass[envcountsect]{beamer}
\usetheme[secheader]{Madrid}    
\usecolortheme{seahorse}
\useoutertheme{infolines}



\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}



\title[Title]{Title}

\subtitle{\small Title}

\author[Author]{Author}

\institute{University of Disneyworld}

\date{02/07/2022}



\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{footline}
{
  \leavevmode%
  \hbox{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{author in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\insertshortauthor
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{title in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshorttitle
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{date in head/foot}% %''right'' as option
    \usebeamerfont{date in head/foot}\insertshortdate{}\hspace*{2em}
   % Making the next line a comment, erases the number of slides
   \insertframenumber{} / \inserttotalframenumber\hspace*{2ex} 
  \end{beamercolorbox}}%
  \vskip0pt%
}
\makeatother

\AtBeginSection[]
{
  \begin{frame}<beamer>
    \frametitle{Outline}
    \tableofcontents[currentsection]
  \end{frame}
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}



\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Frametitle}
Frame
\end{frame}


\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Outline}
\tableofcontents[hideallsubsections]
\end{frame}



%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\section{Section}


\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Frame}
Frame
\end{frame}



\subsection{Subsection}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Frame}
Frame
\end{frame}




\subsection{Subsection}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Frame}
Frame
\end{frame}



\subsection{Subsection}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Frame}
Frame
\end{frame}



%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\section{Section}


\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Frame}
Frame
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

Right now the 'section' frames, along with the frames with the 'section-with-subsection' frame, enter in the overall count, which is something I would like to get rid of, along with the first page. Also, there is no bibliography in this MWE, but a solution should take into account the possibility of having slides devoted to the bibliography.

Thanks a lot in advance for your help!

PS: Is there a way in which we can get rid of the frame number on the very first frame?

Answer (score 1):

You can exclude certain frames from increasing the framenumber with the `noframenumbering` frame option (I would only use this option with the `plain` option or remove the footline on these frames -- otherwise it looks strange if these frames have the same number as the frames after them)

```
\documentclass[envcountsect]{beamer}
\usetheme[secheader]{Madrid}    
\usecolortheme{seahorse}
\useoutertheme{infolines}



\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}



\title[Title]{Title}

\subtitle{\small Title}

\author[Author]{Author}

\institute{University of Disneyworld}

\date{02/07/2022}



\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{footline}
{
  \leavevmode%
  \hbox{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{author in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\insertshortauthor
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{title in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshorttitle
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{date in head/foot}% %''right'' as option
    \usebeamerfont{date in head/foot}\insertshortdate{}\hspace*{2em}
   % Making the next line a comment, erases the number of slides
   \insertframenumber{} / \inserttotalframenumber\hspace*{2ex} 
  \end{beamercolorbox}}%
  \vskip0pt%
}
\makeatother

\AtBeginSection[]
{
  \begin{frame}<beamer>[noframenumbering,plain]
    \frametitle{Outline}
    \tableofcontents[currentsection]
  \end{frame}
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[noframenumbering,plain]
\titlepage
\end{frame}



\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Frametitle}
Frame
\end{frame}


\begin{frame}[noframenumbering,plain]
\frametitle{Outline}
\tableofcontents[hideallsubsections]
\end{frame}



%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\section{Section}


\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Frame}
Frame
\end{frame}



\subsection{Subsection}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Frame}
Frame
\end{frame}




\subsection{Subsection}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Frame}
Frame
\end{frame}



\subsection{Subsection}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Frame}
Frame
\end{frame}



%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\section{Section}


\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Frame}
Frame
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

[image]